# Getting Bus Error in specific cases with this Python C Extension

Tags: python, c

I'm learning C and also at the same time attempting to implement a Python C Extension, this works perfectly until I pass it a list that is rather large...

Example..

```
>>> import shuffle
>>> shuffle.riffle(range(100))
```

Works Great!

```
>>> shuffle.riffle(range(1000))
Bus Error: 10
```

Any ideas as to what my problem is?

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static PyObject *shuffle_riffle(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    int const MAX_STREAK = 10;
    int m, f, l, end_range, streak, *current_ptr;
    double length;

    PyObject * origList;
    PyObject * shuffledList;
    srand((int)time(NULL));

    // parse args to list
    if (! PyArg_ParseTuple( args, "O!", &PyList_Type, &origList) )
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    length = (int)PyList_Size(origList);
    current_ptr = (rand() % 2) ? &f : &l;
    end_range = (int)(length / 2) + (rand() % (length > 10 ? (int)(.1 * length) : 2));
    shuffledList = PyList_New((int)length);

    for(m = 0, f = 0, l = (end_range + 1), streak = 0; m < length && l < length && f < end_range + 1; m++, *current_ptr += 1)
    {
        double remaining = 1 - m / length;
        double test = rand() / (double)RAND_MAX;

        if (test < remaining || streak > MAX_STREAK)
        {
            current_ptr = (current_ptr == &f ? &l : &f);
            streak = 0;
        }

        PyList_SetItem(shuffledList, m, PyList_GetItem(origList, *current_ptr));
        streak += 1;
    }

    // change the pointer to the one that didn't cause the for to exit
    current_ptr = (current_ptr == &f ? &l : &f);

    while(m < length)
    {
        PyList_SetItem(shuffledList, m, PyList_GetItem(origList, *current_ptr));
        m++;
        *current_ptr += 1;
    }



    return Py_BuildValue("O", shuffledList);

}

static PyMethodDef ShuffleMethods[] = {
    {"riffle", shuffle_riffle, METH_VARARGS, "Simulate a Riffle Shuffle on a List."},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

void initshuffle(void){
    (void) Py_InitModule("shuffle", ShuffleMethods);
}
```

Comment: After which line does the Bus Error occur?

Comment: @ouah after some `printf` action, It looks like it's making it all the way to the `while` loop and failing at the `while` declaration and/or first iteration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see three problems with your code.

First, `PyList_GetItem` returns a borrowed reference and `PyList_SetItem` steals the reference which means that you will end up with two lists pointing to the same object but the object's reference count will be 1 instead of 2. This will definitely cause serious problems down the road (Python will at some point try to delete an already-deleted object).

Second, you aren't checking for errors. You should check the return value of all Python calls and if you detect a problem, decref all references that you hold and return `NULL`.

For example:

```
PyObject *temp = PyList_GetItem(origList, *current_ptr);
if (temp == NULL) {
    Py_DECREF(shuffledList);
    return NULL;
}
```

Then, because of the first problem, you have to incref the reference when setting the item:

```
PyList_SET_ITEM(shuffledList, m, temp);
Py_INCREF(temp);
```

You can use the `PyList_SET_ITEM` macro here because you know that the `shuffledList` is un-initialized yet.

Third, you're leaking a reference to the `shuffledList` object in this line:

```
return Py_BuildValue("O", shuffledList);
```

This is equivalent to:

```
Py_INCREF(shuffledList);
return shuffledList;
```

Since you already own the reference (because you created this object), you want to return it directly:

```
return shuffledList;
```

Leaking a reference means that this list will never be freed from memory.

Comment: Post edit... Again, thanks so much, learned a lot and have it working.